# How to Split The key of the List

Tags: python, python-3.x

**I want the same output in the both cases :**

1) `testList = [("Sita", 1), ("Sita", 2), ("Ram", 3), ("Ram", 4), ("Shyam", 5)]`

**I have the solution of 1st case**

```
    out1 = list(map(lambda v:(v[0], sum(map(itemgetter(1), v[1]))), groupby(testList, itemgetter(0))))
print(out1)
```

2)

```
testList = [("Sita_English", 1), ("Sita_Maths", 2), ("Ram_English", 3), ("Ram_Maths", 4), ("Shyam_English", 5)]
```

**And want to have a same output just like 1st case :**

**Output:**

```
[('Sita', 3), ('Ram', 7), ('Shyam', 5)]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can split on `'_'` and keep that as `key` to `group`:

```
out1 = list(map(lambda v: (v[0], sum(map(itemgetter(1), v[1]))), groupby(testList, key=lambda x: x[0].split('_')[0])))
```

A more readable version of the same would be it's equivalent list comprehension:

```
out1 = [(k, sum(x[1] for x in g)) for k, g in groupby(testList, key=lambda x: x[0].split('_')[0])]
```

This requires that all `'Sita'`s, `'Ram'`s and `'Shyam'`s come together. In the else case, you need to sort by the names before doing `groupby`.